# Unexpected redirection during OTP verification process in Flutter Firebase authentication

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm encountering an unexpected issue in my Flutter application where, upon initiating the OTP verification process for phone authentication using Firebase, the app redirects to my SIH project website for verification, displays a "Verifying not a robot" message, and then redirects back to the OTP screen in my app.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


class AuthenticationRepository extends GetxController
{
  static AuthenticationRepository get instance => Get.find();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late final Rx<User?> firebaseUser;
  var verificationId = ' '.obs;

  @override
  void onReady()
  {
    firebaseUser = _auth.currentUser as Rx<User?>;
    firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.userChanges());
    ever(firebaseUser, _setInitialScreen);
  }

  _setInitialScreen(User? user)
  {
    //user == null ? Get.offAll(() => const WelcomeScreen()) : Get.offAll(() => const Dashboard());
  }

  Future<void> phoneAuthentication(String phoneNo) async {
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNo,
        verificationCompleted: (credentials) async{
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credentials);
        },
        verificationFailed: (e){
          if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number'){
            Get.snackbar('Error', 'The provided phone number is not valid');
          }
          else{
            Get.snackbar('Error', 'Something went wrong try again !');
          }
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, resendToken){
          this.verificationId.value = verificationId;
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId){
          this.verificationId.value = verificationId;
        }
    );
  }

  Future<bool> verifyOTP(String otp) async{
    var credentials = await _auth.signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: this.verificationId.value, smsCode: otp));
    return credentials.user != null ? true : false;
  }


}
```

The above is my code and expected result would have been

The app should handle the OTP verification process internally without any redirection to external websites.

Things I've tried:

Checked Firebase project settings for any unintended redirect URLs.
Reviewed the code for any unintended navigation actions.
Tested the app on different devices to rule out device-specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is happen only in **debug** mode. Test the APK on release mode. It will work just fine.